# React lazy - белый экран

Tags: reactjs, lazyloading

Доброго времени суток!

Проблема при добавлении ленивой загрузки.
У меня есть страница с товарами. Есть кнопка "показать подробную информацию о товаре" - которая открывает модальное окно, в котором все описание. Это описание довольно большое, там слайдеры, разные анимации и  куча текста. Я хотел бы запихнуть содержимое модального окна в ленивый компонент, чтоб все эти картинки, слайдеры и тд грузились только тогда, когда юзер нажимает "показать подробную информацию о товаре", а не сразу при загрузке страницы товаров (т.к если все подгружается сразу - приложение жестко тормозит)

Суть проблемы. Я добавляю React lazy компоненту модального окна, но по итогу получаю белый экран, который перекрывает абсолютно все и приложение в принципе не работает.
Я еще изучаю реакт, поэтому не могу пока понять в чем проблема.

const ProductMore = React.lazy(() => import('../ProductMore/ProductMore'));

```
                            <button className="product-bottom-buttons-more-btn"
                                    onClick={() => setIsShowProduct(true)}>Подробнее
                            </button> // сама кнопка подробнее

                                <Modal visible={isShowProduct} setVisible={setIsShowProduct}> //модалка
                                        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                                            <ProductMore product={product} /> //компонент подробнее
                                        </Suspense>
                                </Modal>
```

Comment: Что вам говорит браузер? Без ошибки, сложно дать какой либо ответ

Comment: 1) Warning: lazy: Expected the result of a dynamic import() call. Instead received: [object Module]

Your code should look like: 
  const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'))
а дальше перечисление куча компонентов элементов дивов и тд

2) Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.

3) The above error occurred in one of your React components:

Comment: Компонент из `import('../ProductMore/ProductMore'))` экспортирукется по умолчанию?

Comment: Я поменял экспорт на по умолчанию и теперь вроде как все работает. Только объясните пожалуйста, почему экспорт по умолчанию так важен для ленивой подгрузки?

Comment: На сколько я понял(я с lazy не работал), можно импортировать и без дефолтного экспорта, немного дописав фукнцию импорта.